# NPPExec Console in NotePad

Tags: unix, notepad++

Thanks in advance:

I'm attempting to use Notepad++ to log-in to a UNIX system. I am using the NPPExec console to do this, and the login process works... kind of. I use NPPExec to execute this script, named "sasunix.sh":

"C:\userblah\username\Desktop\plink.exe" -load "SUN4" -l myloginname -pw mypassword

As you can see I am using Putty's command line program "plink.exe" to send the command; "SUN4" is the session profile I am using. The problem is, the next screen logs me in (successfully), but proceeds to ask me for my password an additional time (which is part of the login procedure), followed by a request for my my terminal emulation setting (for me, this is 'xterm').

THE QUESTION: What additional lines would I add to my script to execute this sequence of inputs on the UNIX system (i.e. typing them in individually and pressing "ENTER" each time):

1.) thepassword 2.) xterm 3.) sas -nodms -nonews

I think this boils down to a misunderstanding of how commands are passed between NotePad++ and the NPPExec console window. At any point, if I press "F6", a prompt pops up, saying "WARNING: Console process still running...". This messagebox prompt allows me to type in a line which is then sent to the console... but how do I put a series of these inputs into the script?

Answer (score 0):

You prob have this solved by now,
but i have done the following

1. a windows batch script that creates a file with unix commands, based on the a directory path

   ```
   @ECHO OFF

   :: store input variable

   set str=%1

   :: remove C:\ or Z:\ etc

   set str=%str:~3%

   :: replace \ with /

   set str=%str:\=/%

   :: append cd command

   set str1=cd

   set str=%str1% %str%

   echo.%str%

   :: make

   echo make clean

   echo make all
   ```
2. Install the NppExec plugin to Notepad++
3. Place the *.bat scripts and plink.exe in the Notepad++ program directory
4. Create the NppExec commands

   ```
   // This line calls the bat file and creates a file tempcmd.sh with unix commands in it
   "$(NPP_DIRECTORY)\unix_make_all.bat" $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) >tempcmd.sh`


    // This line connects to a remote machine and runs all the commands stored in tempcmd.sh
    "$(NPP_DIRECTORY)\plink.exe" -ssh -2 -l username -pw password 192.168.000.000 -m "$(NPP_DIRECTORY)\tempcmd.sh"
   ```
5. Using the NppExec options i save the above commands and place a shortcut in the macros menu